# Как правильно парсить используя PHPQuery?

Tags: php, парсер, curl, phpquery, parse

Имеется страница со следующей структурой товара:

```
<div class="entry">
   <div class="entry-thumbnail">
      <a href="https://site.com/product/krossovki-ad/">
         <div class="image " style="background-image: url(&quot;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/photo_2022-12-19_14-11-35-200x200.jpg&quot;); height: 200px;" data-width="200" data-height="200"></div>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="entry-data">
      <div class="entry-header">
         <a class="entry-title" href="https://site.com/product/krossovki-ad/">
            <h3>Кроссовки ASD-12</h3>
         </a>
      </div>
      <span class="price"><span class="prefix"></span> <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>89<span class="decimals">.00</span>&nbsp;<span class="currency"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">usd.</span></span></bdi></span></span>
      <form class="cart" action="https://site.com/product/krossovki-ad/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div class="quantity">
            <input type="number" step="1" min="1" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол-во" class="input-text qty text" size="4">
         </div>
         <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="117516" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">В корзину</button>
      </form>
   </div>
   <div class="entry-additions">
      <span class="price"><span class="prefix"></span> <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>89<span class="decimals">.00</span>&nbsp;<span class="currency"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">usd.</span></span></bdi></span></span>
      <form class="cart" action="https://site.com/product/krossovki-ad/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div class="quantity">
            <input type="number" step="1" min="1" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол-во" class="input-text qty text" size="4">
         </div>
         <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="117516" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">В корзину</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

попробовал парсить имя товара посредством PHPQuery (Curl function):

```
function getcontents($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
 
include_once __DIR__ . '/phpQuery.php';
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument(getcontents('https://site.com/asd-shoes/'));

$entry = $doc->find('.entry-title');
foreach($entry as $row){
$data['entry-title'][] = pq($row)->text();
}
print_r($data['entry-title']);
```

получил массив данных с именами товаров, но никак не пойму как правильно парсить изображение, которое заключен внутри стиля `style="background-image: url(&quot;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/photo_2022-12-19_14-11-35-200x200.jpg&quot;);"`, и как парсить цену так чтобы, в итоге получился массив:

```
p_name => Имя товара
p_price => Цена товара
p_image => Ссылка изображения товара
```

чтобы правильно получить данные по всем товарам на странице, прошу помочь ЭКСПеРТОВ с данной головоломкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я конечно не ЭКСП РТОВ :), но могу предложить: получать нужный элемент, у него с помощью функции **attr(string)** либо **text()** (в зависимости от того что нужно) получать содержимое и с помощью [**preg_match**](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) получать итоговые значения, пример получения ссылки на изображение:

```php
<?php
preg_match("(background-image: url\((.+)\))", pq($doc->find(".image")[0])->attr("style"), $array);
var_dump($array); /* Выведет: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(116) "background-image: url(&quot;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/photo_2022-12-19_14-11-35-200x200.jpg&quot;)"
  [1]=>
  string(93) "&quot;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/photo_2022-12-19_14-11-35-200x200.jpg&quot;"
} */
echo substr($array[1], 6, -6); // Пример удаления "&quot;" из получаемой ссылки (выведет: https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/photo_2022-12-19_14-11-35-200x200.jpg)
?>
```

Надеюсь дальше справитесь сами, но если что, пишите)